# Order SELECT Statement from joined tables by variable

Tags: php, sql, datetime

I am trying to order my query results by a variable created from a date calculation from the database..

I have a row in my db called "DateInStock" which is a VARCHAR and inputted from a csv file like so - 9/9/2015

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM csv INNER JOIN kbb ON csv.VIN=kbb.Vin ORDER BY $numberDays DESC");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {

// Calculate Days in Stock
$todaydate = date("m/d/Y");
$dis = $row['DateInStock'];
$startTimeStamp = strtotime($todaydate);
$endTimeStamp = strtotime($dis);
$timeDiff = abs($endTimeStamp - $startTimeStamp);
$numberDays = $timeDiff/86400;  // 86400 seconds in one day
$numberDays = intval($numberDays);

echo $numberDays;
}
```

So $numberDays gives me the number of days its been in stock..

```
echo $numberdays; // Gives me 40, 38, 30 etc.. for each iteration
```

I would like to order the query results by $numberDays either DESC or ASC

Comment: What do you mean by _out of whack_? Also, could you show what your output is, and what output you would expect?

Comment: Is DateInStock a DATE datatype or something else?

Comment: DateInStock is inputted to the database from a csv file..Its already formatted like that when inputted. @David I cant seem to find a order thats what I mean by out of whack.. It changes the order but cant seem to find the pattern.. I would like it outputted as dateInStock from most recent to oldest

Comment: try explicitly casting csv.DateInStock as a date in the order by. It feels like mySQL is treating it as something other than a date

Comment: The field in the db is a VARCHAR would that matter?

Comment: Quite possibly. Instead of ordering it as a data it could be ordering it as a string, which depending on your date format could be very out of whack: order by STR_TO_DATE(csv.DateInStock, '%d/%m/%Y') desc

Comment: That changes the order but still no order to the order if you know what I mean, they  are out of sequence

Comment: If you can it would be more efficient. Casting like in my last comment's edit will do the job though if you don't have millions of rows to process

Comment: There is roughly 180 rows

Comment: I cannot change the dateInStock from VARCHAR or it wont import

Comment: I update dthe Select Statement to show what I would really like as I eventually would like to filter results based on different variable I have for different calculations like "Top Gross" etc..

Answer (score 0):

It would be much more efficiently to use date/timestamp data type for your 'DateInStock' column. But you can convert it to the date data type on the fly:

```
create table aaa(dt varchar(30));

insert into aaa values
('2015-12-01'),('2016-01-01'),('2016-01-10'),('2016-01-20');
```

SQL:

```
select datediff(cast(dt as date), now()) as diff from aaa;
```

Output:

```
diff
-62
-31
-22
-12
```

Here is [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/24d0b/2)

Answer (score 0):

Ok Thanks to @LordBaconPants this did it -

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM csv INNER JOIN kbb ON csv.VIN=kbb.Vin ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(DateInStock, '%m/%d/%Y') DESC ");
```

That fixes the issue of the date in the db but still need to know how to use a calculated variable to sort the query so I may be back.. Thanks all!